# GREP each nth line starting from first

Tags: grep

I need to print each nth line (like each 4th line example) of a bunch of content starting from first line.I am allowed to use GREP not sed or head (i know how to do that with Sed). I need to use GREP again.

Anyone has any idea ?

Comment: Could you supply some example of input data and an example of the desired output?

Comment: an example in a file with 300 lines i need to print first line, 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th, 25th and so on.

Comment: No, [edit] your question to include concise, testable, concrete sample input and expected output don't just describe an idea of what you want in a comment. And explain why you need to use `grep` as that's the wrong tool for a task like this, you should be using `awk` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will print every 5th line. I don't think it is exactly what you are looking for, but perhaps it will help.

```
grep -n '.*' INPUT_FILE.txt | grep -E '^[0-9]+[05]:'
```

The first grep is just there to number the lines, and the second grep will match line numbers ending with 0 and 5. Maybe this can be adapted to meet your needs.

Edit: The first solution I posted was incorrect (first grep needed -n, thanks Ed Morton)

Comment: @Ed Morton: Hmm...not sure what I was thinking originally (I must have been using `nl`) but I have now corrected the answer. `grep -n` will number lines as you correctly stated.